# Additional loader required to handle the result of these loaders

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am facing this error how to resolve this I've tried a lot but no success

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-scheduler-pro/src/lib/index.tsx 7:15
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:15)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  | import { SchedulerProps } from './types';
  |

> const Scheduler: React.FC = (props: any) => {
> |   return (
> |

```
import React from 'react';
import StoreProvider from './store/provider';
import SchedulerComponent from './Components';
import '../App.scss';
import { SchedulerProps } from './types';

const Scheduler: React.FC<SchedulerProps> = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <StoreProvider initial={props}>
      <SchedulerComponent {...props} />
    </StoreProvider>
  );
};

export { Scheduler };
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  target: "node",
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "lib", "index.tsx"),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "index.js",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.scss$/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"] },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx|cjs)?$/,
        enforce: "pre",
        use: ["source-map-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "ts-loader",
            options: {
              configFile: "tsconfig.build.json",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-scheduler-pro",
  "version": "0.2.9",
  "author": "Owais Ahmad",
  "license": "MIT",
  "files": [
    "*"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.2.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.8",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.4",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.8",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "date-fns-tz": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-popper": "^2.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.62.1",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "pack": "rm -rf dist && npm run webpack && npm run post:pack",
    "local:pack": "npm run pack && cd dist && npm pack && mv *.tgz ../",
    "format": "prettier --check .",
    "format:write": "prettier --write .",
    "lint": "npm run types && eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --fix",
    "types": "tsc --noEmit",
    "pre:commit": "lint-staged",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:ci": "jest --ci"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/Owais-Ahmed7/react-scheduler-pro.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "calendar",
    "scheduler",
    "appointments scheduler",
    "events scheduler",
    "resource scheduler"
  ],
  "homepage": "",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Owais-Ahmed7/react-scheduler-pro/issues"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.23.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.1.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.0",
    "lint-staged": "^15.2.2",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "sass-loader": "^14.1.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.4",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "webpack": "^5.90.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.2",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.js

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true, 
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "strictNullChecks":false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["src/lib/**/*"]
}
```